# SQL Server, CPU

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2017 Express Edition only recognizes one CPU in AUTO when four are assigned. I can reassign the affinity so that it recognizes the rest, but the affinity type changes to MANUAL and it does not dynamically distribute the processes, but only does so in one. My SQL server is on Linux 20.04.

I tried to replicate it in a virtual machine but when I see which ones it assigns by AUTO, all of them are reflected, not just one.

Answer (score 2):

[Express edition only supports the lesser of 1 socket or 4 cores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2022?view=sql-server-ver16#scale-limits). You didn't post the VM configuration but I'd venture a guess it's setup at 4 socket/4 cores instead of 1 socket 4 cores.

Comment: No, the server is configured as 4 socket, 4 cores and the vm is 1 socket, 4 cores,

Comment: If the VM was configured for 1 socket and 4 cores then it'd use 1 socket up to 4 cores. That's the Express edition limitations.

Comment: Exactly, you said it, 4 cores but the server only takes 1

Comment: Then you'll need to post the sys.configurations output, startup errorlog, and sys.dm_os_schedulers output